# Array with Range.Autofilter is not working

Tags: excel, vb.net, range, autofilter

In VB.net, I was trying to filter the excel column using array and the "does not equal" option. But only the last value in the array was used for filtering. There was no effect on other array item values.
Excel input:

```
**Table**
sfsf
hello
hi
hello
```

I am using the syntax below:

```
ws.Range(range).AutoFilter (field:=fieldnumber, Criteria1:=(AAA), 
Operator:=CType(x1And,XlAutoFilterOperator))
```

Where AAA has the value ("<>hi","<>hello")
The result is :

```
**Table**
sfsf
hi
```

Any one have any idea how i can filter out all the items other than mentioned in the array using vb.net.

Comment: I assume this is `VBA` (Visual Basic for Applications) and not `VB.Net` if it's the scripting in Excel?

Comment: @RazorKillBen - no, it is VB.Net... the use of [`Ctype`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/ctype-function) is one clue.

Comment: That `1` in on `x1And` looks like a typo, should be the letter `l` as in Lima.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to filter two values that are not equal to `x` then you need to add the second criteria separately:

```vb
ws.Range(range).AutoFilter (field:=fieldnumber, Criteria1:="<>hi", _
    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>hello"
```

If you're trying to filter out two criterias that contain that word, you'll need to add a wildcard to your criteria like the below:

```vb
ws.Range(range).AutoFilter (field:=fieldnumber, Criteria1:="<>*hi*", _
    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>*hello*"
```

Comment: Thnaks for your response RazorKillBen, What if i need to exclude more than 2 items..

Comment: You can simply keep extending the code to add `Criteria3` and separate with `xlAnd` or `xlOr`